# Ranking sum in mysql

Tags: mysql, rank

I have a Mysql query, where I am trying to sum a column, and rank by the total.

Here is my query:

```
select 
@rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
sum(length) as total,
user_id
from submissions,
(select @rownum:=0) a WHERE id = 1067 AND status = 1
group by user_id
 order by total desc
```

This results in:

```
rank    total    user_id    
 2      65.25     1360
 1      59.50     1151
 4      58.00     1250
 6      55.75     1374
 5      51.25     1154
 3      34.75      841
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have to use an inner query to grab totals first then rank them with an outter select like this:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank,
       total,
       user_id
from 
    (select sum(length) as total,
            user_id
     from submissions
     WHERE id = 1067 AND status = 1
     group by user_id
     order by total desc)T,(select @rownum:=0)a
```